# Expected Linear time Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm

Tags: randomness, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to understand the proposed "Randomized Linear-Time Algorithm to Find MST".

My findings:
I have read and search almost every available resource( [main paper](http://cs.brown.edu/research/pubs/pdfs/1995/Karger-1995-RLT.pdf), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_linear_time_MST_algorithm), [reports on paper](http://cs-www.bu.edu/faculty/homer/537/talks/Tsai-CS537_Report.pdf), [lecture on paper](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring15/compsci590.1/scribing/cps590_lec15.pdf) ) but not getting any clue regarding my confusion.

Question: 
In the [original paper](http://cs.brown.edu/research/pubs/pdfs/1995/Karger-1995-RLT.pdf) **Section 3: The Algorithm** "***Step 2***" says "In the contracted graph, choose a subgraph H by selecting each edge independently with probability 1/2."

If I have 6 vertexes with 14 edges. And if I choose 7 edges with probability 1/2 then there might be some isolated vertex. In that case, what will happen to that isolated vertex?

Comment: What do you mean by "choose 7 edges with probability 1/2"? You choose each edge with probability 1/2. You might choose 0 edges or 14 edges. The probability to choose exactly 7 edges is only 21%.

Comment: I have lack knowledge of probability. So, I misinterpret that part. Let me rephrase what I understood. "Choosing anything with probability 1/2 means, either I will choose it, or I will not choose it. And chances of choosing it 1/2 also chances of not choosing it 1/2." In other cases, if it says "Choosing anything with probability 1/4 means, either I will choose it, or I will not choose it. And chances of choosing it 1/4 and chances of not choosing it 3/4."

Please let me know if I am correct.

Comment: It is impossible to understand randomized algorithms without a good grasp of elementary probability theory. I suggest you learn enough probability to be able to calculate the probability that exactly 7 edges are chosen, and only then proceed in your efforts to understand this particular algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in particular happens if there is an isolated vertex. The algorithm is correct even if $H$ consists of no edges, or if it consists of all edges. The algorithm proceeds by finding a minimum spanning forest on $H$, and using it to prune the contracted graph. IF $H$ consists of no edges, then nothing is pruned, but the algorithm remains correct - this only affects the running time.

Note also that the algorithm is for the more general minimum spanning *forest* problem. Hence there is absolutely no problem if the graph is not connected. The algorithm will find a minimum spanning tree in each connected component.